# Custom Actions within c++/cli Setup project

Tags: c++-cli, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have done over 20 installer classes for MSI's in c#, i'm now attempting one in c++/cli. I add my project output file (which contains my installer class) to the custom actions "Install"... i over ride OnAfterInstall within the Installer Class, with no code at the moment and i get the following error (just testing):

Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.10.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT
with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x30131019).

i would appreciate any guidance on this issue... I've never experienced it before. when this error happens it initiates a rollback... below is a link to the MSI LOG:

http://www.evas.com/MSILOG/MSI67b70.LOG

i would greatly appreciate some guidance,
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've only written [this type of custom actions in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) so I don't know for sure what is the problem.

I found on MSDN the following samples, maybe it will help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.71).aspx